# How to remove all options from a Dijit FilteringSelect widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo, dijit.form

I tried removing all options from dijit.form.filteringselect and adding an option to dijit.form.filteringselect using the below function. However, I am getting an error: *no method getOptions and addOption*. am using dojo 1.7

```
function showTablesDropDown(tableDiv){
  dijit.byId(tableDiv).removeOption(dijit.byId(tableDiv).getOptions());
  dijit.byId(tableDiv).addOption(dojo.create("option", {label:"None", value:"None"}));
}
```

How to remove all options from dijit.form.filteringselect and add option to dijit.form.filteringselect?

Comment: Why do you have `dijit.byId(tableDiv)`?

Comment: dijit.byId(tableDiv) is ID of filteringselect

Comment: is there any solution? @DimitriM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is just a slight misunderstanding of how the `FilteringSelect` (and anything that inherits from `_AutoCompleterMixin`) interacts with its data. Regardless of how you are creating the `FilteringSelect` widget, the underlying mechanism for controlling its options is an object that adheres to the [Dojo Store API](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store.html#id3).

This means that in order to modify your `FilteringSelect` widget's options, you need to interact with this `store` instead.  I've [set up this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGt5n/13/) to demonstrate, but basically you want to change your function to something like:

```
function showTablesDropDown(tableDiv){
   var filteringSelectWidget = dijit.byId(tableDiv);

   // Clear current value since options are changing.
   filteringSelectWidget.set("value", ""); 

   var store = filteringSelectWidget.get("store");
   var newData = [{label: "None", value: "None"}];    

   // Give the underlying store a new data array.
   store.setData(newData);
}
```

Comment: i don't want to add {label:"None", value:"None"} to store. so i tried this. dijit.byId(tableDiv).set("value",{label:"None", value:"None"}); but its not working

Comment: i think your example is to replace the store and adding newData to store. i dn't want to replace store, just wanted to add new option in dijit.byId(tableDiv) not to store

Comment: Well, your `FilteringSelect` widget uses a store to hold all of your options. Therefore, you don't just add an item directly to the `FilteringSelect`, rather, you add the item to the `FilteringSelect`'s store. So you want to just add a new item to the store (and keep all the original items)? Or are you just trying to set the `FilteringSelect`'s value to something that does not yet exist as an option?